# Can't find saved passwords in Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, passwords

I use Google Chrome on Linux. I use KDE, and moreover, KDE Wallet is not enabled. So I think the "Plain text" method of storing passwords should be in use.

Chrome successfully saves passwords but I can not find them anywhere! And this means I can not move them to a different machine, reinstall Linux, etc.

chrome://settings/passwords#passwords is empty. On passwords.google.com I see only ten sites and I think I saved passwords to them on my phone, not my PC.

Where might all those other passwords be? And how can i retrieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. It is an outright bug in Chrome. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251355

I have also made a kludgey workaround, based on a script I found on github. https://github.com/mramendi/chrome_password_grabber/tree/google-fix

Answer (score 2):

My solution has been to open `chrome://flags/#clean-undecryptable-passwords`

Set to enabled and restart chrome, go back there and set to default again.

Autocompletion works again!

source https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251355#c33

Comment: For some reason that wasn't quite enough, so I also enabled `chrome://flags/#skip-undecryptable-passwords` and now it seems to work. Nice one! No idea why that wouldn't be enabled by default...

Comment: These options used to work, but they don't seem to be available anymore in Chrome 119...

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes filed under Auto Fill. Try clicking on the 3 dots in the top right, going to the settings menu, and checking both the "Passwords" and "Auto Fill" options that should be in plain site.

Failing that, it could be on your Google Account. Are you signed in to there on Chrome?

If all else fails, you could copy and paste your entire Chrome profile on to a new browser. If there's passwords in there, then they'll carry over. Hopefully they're not stored by the very old school cookies methods.